# Does vector::erase re-order elements in vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector contains a,b,c,d,e
vec[2] is c, but will it automatically reorder after i delete/erase c ? i mean vec[2] is d after the operation.

Comment: It should be easy to check, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. What would the alternative be?

Comment: @john: One alternative would be to leave an empty slot, and account for that in the behaviour of the iterators and accessor functions. Of course, that would break the requirement for contiguous storage, and probably some of the performance requirements too.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Another possibility is to swap the element to be deleted with the last element, and then do a `pop_back`.  This would improve the performance notably (in most cases, anyway), and would meet all of the other requirements of `vector`, except the requirement that the order not be perturbed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually, I think it would be very difficult to check.  I think that the standard guarantees that `erase` leaves the order of all other elements unchanged, but I'm not sure where to find it.  And the fact that the implementation I'm using doesn't change the order doesn't prove that an implementation isn't allowed to change the order.  (Well, it does, sort of: changing the order allows a far more efficient implementation, which presumably the implementations would use if it were allowed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically yes, as a vector is a dynamic array of element. You delete one, then everything that follows is moved.

In the same manner, the total length of the vector will decrease as you erase elements.

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

> This effectively reduces the vector size by the number of elements
>   removed, calling each element's destructor before.
>
> Because vectors keep an array format, erasing on positions other than
>   the vector end also moves all the elements after the segment erased to
>   their new positions, which may not be a method as efficient as erasing
>   in other kinds of sequence containers (deque, list).

Comment: thanks. i think that's why iterators are used through "for". iterators are dynamic, too. am i right ?

Comment: Iterators are invalidated in case of modification on the collection. From the same source: "This invalidates all iterator and references to position (or first) and its subsequent elements."

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard:

> **iterator erase(const_iterator position);**
>
> ....
>
> Effects: Invalidate iterators and references at or after the point of the erase
>
> Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements erased, but the move assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements.

As you see the move assignment operator will be called as many times as there are elements after the erased element, and every reference/iterator to the elements after are invalidated.

So when one element is erased, all elements following are moved to fill in the "blank" space where the erased element was.

The point about the invalidated references/iterators are very important to remember, esp. if you are erasing in a loop. According to the newest standard erase should return you an iterator to the next element which you could use, or the [erase-and-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the side effects of this during an iteration, use the [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)